# Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("methodname") is not a valid method for this service

Tags: php, xml

I am getting the following error when trying to Authenticate SOAP Requests

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] Function ("methodname") is not a valid method for this service in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php:7 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php(7): SoapClient->__call('methodname', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php(7): SoapClient->methodname(Object(SoapHeader)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\api.php on line 7

Below is the PHP code I have written:

```
<?php
$apiauth =array('Token'=>'string');
$wsdl = 'https://testtiwi.europaeiske.dk/ecommerceprivateservice.asmx?wsdl';
$header = new SoapHeader('http://webs.europaeiske.dk', 'SecurityToken', $apiauth);
$soap = new SoapClient($wsdl); 
$soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);       
$data = $soap->methodname($header); 
?>
```

Following is the WSDL code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <SecurityToken xmlns="http://webs.europaeiske.dk">
            <Token>string</Token>
        </SecurityToken>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <ProductTerms xmlns="http://webs.europaeiske.dk">
            <productCode>string</productCode>
            <tripData>
                <StartDate>string</StartDate>
                <EndDate>string</EndDate>
                <TripType>string</TripType>
                <GeographicalZone>string</GeographicalZone>
                <DestinationList>
                    <string>string</string>
                    <string>string</string>
                </DestinationList>
            </tripData>
        </ProductTerms>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Please help me to fix the error?

Comment: The error is pretty clear. You're calling `methodname()` which doesn't exist in the web service you're using.

Comment: Looks like `methodname()` does not exist. `var_dump($client->__getFunctions());` Run this to get the list of functions at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks :) my code is working.